# java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket

Tags: tomcat, eofexception

We are observing a lot of these errors in the logs.

> java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket

Following is the protocol configured in the server.xml of Tomcat8 Instance:

```
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol.
```

Do we have to replace the above mentioned protocol with the following?

```
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol
```

Answer (score 1):

> Do we have to replace the above mentioned protocol with the following?

No. You need to check if some clients are causing these exceptions, for example with a network capture. "Buggy" clients could be monitoring tools, load-balancers doing a health check,.. If the exceptions come on a very regular basis, this would probably indicate such monitoring tools.

If after this investigation, still nothing, check if your applications use logging frameworks such as Log4j, there are such behaviours known when using them.

Comment: Hi 
I found tomcat 8.5.30 changelog has fix related to EOF handling.
PFB.
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/changelog.html

Comment: @PradeepPydi Good job. Upgrading Tomcat solved your issue ?

Comment: Not yet. We should be upgrading soon to the latest version of tomcat.